# How to obtain blocknumber when a value is changed?

Tags: solidity

I can read a public variable in a smart contract.

But in order for me to be sure that the value is confirmed, I need to check the blocknumber when that value is set against the current block number.

May I know if it is possible for me to do that?

emitting an event or store the latest blocknumber together with the value is out of the question here. Because I am looking for a why that we need consume additional gas.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot directly do that. If you have an archive node, you can keep checking the storage of the contract (i.e. `web3.eth.getStorageAt`) against the current block number and keep decreasing this block number until you have reached a value where this storage was different: then you have thus found the block where this storage slot was changed.

A smarter approach here, using less `web3` calls would be to use a binary search on the block number instead of decreasing the block number by `1` every time.

Comment: Thanks JBrouwer, may I know what is the parameter **position** in getStorageAT for? Is that mean I have to manually calculate the index (position) of the parameter inside the contract manually?

Comment: Yes, you have to manually calculate the index of the storage address. This could be rather hard to do: however, it looks like Etherscan has the "state changed" fields which you can use to find the field you are interested in. For instance (arbitrary transaction): https://etherscan.io/tx/0xd1b1257593469800148f73eceed186ca2561cf48c074f1b6f373398b4294e9a9#statechange.  If you check the 0xfac... address you see that storage slot 0xbe..88 changed from 0x00..00 to 0xa7..15. You are thus interested in the slot 0xbe..88 in this case.

Comment: Another possibility is to trace your transaction using web3's `debug_traceTransaction` method and find the step where you `SSTORE` the value you are interested in; the first parameter on the stack is then the storage slot the value is put in.

Comment: Thanks for the detail answer JBrouwer. I will not take this approach for now. Because it is going to be extremely difficult to maintain in future.

Comment: If you want to track it I suggest using events; they do cost some extra gas but not that many (I think about roughly 500 gas).